# How to get Pkg in Julia 0.5? ("ERROR: unknown package Pkg")

Tags: julia

I need to run a code written in Julia 0.5.

I installed this version on macOS and when I run

```
using Pkg
```

It returns the error:

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: Module Pkg not found in current path.
Run `Pkg.add("Pkg")` to install the Pkg package.
 in require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:365
 in require(::Symbol) at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
```

When I run

```
Pkg.add("Pkg")
```

It returns

```
INFO: Initializing package repository /Users/henrique/.julia/v0.5
INFO: Cloning METADATA from https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
ERROR: unknown package Pkg
 in macro expansion at ./pkg/entry.jl:53 [inlined]
 in (::Base.Pkg.Entry.##2#5{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet})() at ./task.jl:360
 in sync_end() at ./task.jl:311
 in macro expansion at ./task.jl:327 [inlined]
 in add(::String, ::Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet) at ./pkg/entry.jl:51
 in (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}})() at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
 in cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}}, ::String) at ./file.jl:59
 in #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
```

How to get `Pkg` in Julia 0.5 then?

Answer (score 3):

That is a very old version of Julia. It is strongly recommended to use a recent version, see the downloads page: https://julialang.org/downloads/. In 0.5 the Pkg module was available by default, so I'm not sure how `using Pkg` doesn't work. In general, if you're following recent instructions, they're not going to work on such an old version of the language.

Comment: Yes, probably rewriting the code to Julia 1 will be easier. Thanks for the advice